# Скроллинг страницы вверх IE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть таблица.
При скроллинге страницы шапка таблицы и информация о консультанте крепится к окну (становится фиксированной). Если нажать на любую строку таблицы, информация о консультанте обновится. В chrome это все работает на ура, но IE скроллит окно в начало страницы, то есть, к началу таблицы.

Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Гадание по картинке будем практиковать?

Comment: Что надо предоставить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Посмотрите, то по чему вы кликаете (строки таблицы), не являются ли они ссылками с пустыми href с хешем, вида a href="#"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить, что обработчики кликов делают preventDefault и stopPropagation или действия с аналогичным результатом. Точнее убедиться, что они этого не делают.

```
<a href=#>
```

Comment: Все верно, в обработчике был метод .focus он и двигал страницу вверх. Убрал его и все стало нормально. Там просто запутано все поэтому не сразу наткнулся на него.

Принцип: при нажатии на строку вызывается click который эмитирует нажатие на кнопку а у кнопки уже свой обработчик в нем и был .focus